# Ask user to choose a certificate and read from the selection

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, x509certificate

I am developing a login page with Blazor Server .Net Core 6 that should use an authentication method with custom certificates that we provide. I already have the certificates installed and can be readed if they are in the server (with CredentialStore and such).

The problem I face is that I want to read the user's certificate, not the ones from the server.

I already tried to require certificate with the IIS but I dont want to force the user to choose certificate first because they have another login method (user and password) and it should be asked when user click a button (Login with certificate or whatever).

From what I read, Core .NET only let user choose certificate at the very beginning of HTTP Connection, even before the first page is loaded.

I was expecting to click a button, show the window with the available certificates for the user and proccess the selection.

Comment: You can't.  TLS the server sends a certificate block with names of possible certificate. The client chooses one of the names.  You have to have the certificate loaded before it can be used.  If you want a different certificate you have to load it on server.  The certificate is never sent using TLS, only the name of certificates.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.